# How to check associations feathers-sequelize in service hook

Tags: javascript, associations, sequelize.js, feathersjs, feathers-sequelize

I`am using [feathersjs](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers).

I have read the [documentation](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/docs/associations/#check-associations).

How do I execute this method to check on the service hook feathers-hook, or tell me another method of check.

```
const { disallow } = require('feathers-hooks-common');

function include() {
  return function (hook) {
    const productPrice = hook.app.service('product-prices').Model;
    const currencies = hook.app.service('currencies').Model;
    const edizm = hook.app.service('edizm').Model;

    const pricesShema = { model: productPrice,
      include: [
        {
          model: currencies,
          attributes: ['title', 'socr']
        },
      ]
    };

    const edizmShema = { model: edizm,
      attributes: ['title', 'detail']
    };

    let association={include: [edizmShema, pricesShema]};
    hook.params.sequelize = Object.assign(association,{ raw: false });

    return Promise.resolve(hook);
  }
}

module.exports = {
  ......
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained [here](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize/issues/127):
Feathers hooks work with POJO's not with DB ORM's, and your `raw: false` returns an ORM.

If you really can't use `raw: true` then convert the ORM to a POJO:

```
const dehydrate = require('feathers-sequelize/hooks/dehydrate');
hooks.after.find = [dehydrate(), discard('password')]
```

You can [convert back to an ORM](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-sequelize/tree/master/src/hooks) (if you really need to).